# Wiki that never loses unsaved content, keeps all revisions, has pretty URLs and double-click editing

Tags: linux, open-source, wiki

I need a FLOSS wiki for installation on a GNU/Linux server that comes with the following features:

**Clean URLs.** Allow visiting specific pages by typing their URL from memory. Example: `https://wiki.example.com/PHP` to visit the wiki page titled "PHP" and `https://wiki.example.com/PHP/edit` to visit its edit form.

**Keep *all* revisions.** Don’t purge them, don’t keep only the last *n* revisions per page.

**Double-click editing.** Double-click anyhwere on a page to load its edit form.

**Never lose unsaved content.** Use caching/JavaScript magic to prevent losing unsaved content when a user tries to submit an edit but lost Internet connection, or accidentally uses the Back button while editing, or closes the browser while in edit mode. These "drafts" don’t *have* to (but may) be saved on the server-side.

Comment: wikimatrix.org has an in depth comparison of over 100 wikis.  They have a choice wizard to help you narrow down the field.

Answer (score 1):

I am biased, but MediaWiki does this.

- Clean URLs: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL . MediaWiki's URLs are designed for free linking, no ugly IDs.
- Keep all revisions: MediaWiki doesn't delete anything! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Principles
- Double-click: that's a preference available in MediaWiki core for section-editing.
- NEVER losing content is quite a hard promise to make, but I've not losted content editing MediaWiki for a long time now... browsers work quite well nowadays and MediaWiki is on the simple textareas side, no surprises. However, there is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Drafts for additional defenses.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds great; especially the 'Automatic Saving' of the Drafts extension. -- For getting a clean editing page URL, I think (after reading the Short URL documentation you linked to)  I have to configure [`$wgActionPaths`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgActionPaths) (the "[action on the end](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgActionPaths#action_on_the_end)" case seems to match my example).

Comment: Yes, action paths are quite neat. As for Drafts, please update me here on how it works for you! In case it doesn't, there's also a smallish patch which provides some basic functionality in MediaWiki core itself, with localStorage: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/5130/23 (later versions of that changeset adopted a different strategy and are not ready yet).